# Bottom aligning bootstrapped thumbnails while keeping them horizontally centered

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have read lots of similar questions and tried to apply the answers by adding divs with position:absolute and relative aroudn the images to the code but I cannot get it to work.

http://store9711.americommerce.com/milk-glass-vases-and-candle-holders.aspx

I need to bottom align these thumbnails while keeping them horizontally centered

Is anyone able to show me how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use the `vertical-align` property

CSS

```
.category-product .thumbnail img {
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: bottom; /*Add this line*/
 }
.category-product .thumbnail{ 
   display:block; 
}
```

Also give `display:block` to the anchor tag to keep the image horizontally center.

Answer (score 1):

```
.category-product .thumbnail img {
display: inline;
vertical-align: bottom; /*add this*/
}
```

The default Bootstrap setup (line 7 of bootstrap.min.css) on your site aligns to middle (applied to `img` HTML element). You'll just need to override for the category images.